# Unable to send JSON as body for HTTP POST request in GO

Tags: go

When i make the POST request using the below GO Function. I get a `invalid json` on the server side.

If i send static json for example

```
var jsonprep = []byte(`{"username":"xyz@gmail.com","password":"xyz123"}`)
```

it does work instead of

```
var jsonprep string = "`{username:"+username+",password:"+password+"}`"
```

.

```
func makeHttpPostReq(url string, username string, password string){

    client := http.Client{}


    var jsonprep string = "`{username:"+username+",password:"+password+"}`"

    var jsonStr = []byte(jsonprep)

    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, bytes.NewBuffer(jsonStr))
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
         fmt.Println("Unable to reach the server.")
    } else {
         body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
         fmt.Println("body=", string(body))
    }

}
```

Comment: In addition to the answers, you can avoid all of the "fragility" around quoting if you marshal your data into JSON from a struct. See here for a minimal example: http://play.golang.org/p/8lGwkQPYxb - you can modify your `makeHttpPostReq` function to accept a `User` instead of two strings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've got your quoting wrong:

http://play.golang.org/p/PueWyQ1atq

```
var jsonprep string = "`{username:"+username+",password:"+password+"}`"

===> `{username:Bob,password:pass}`
```

You meant:

http://play.golang.org/p/LMuwxArf8G

```
var jsonprep string = `{"username":"`+username+`","password":"`+password+`"}`
===> {"username":"Bob","password":"pass"}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use

```
var jsonprep string = "`{username:"+username+",password:"+password+"}`"
```

the server will get the data like this:

```
`{username:your_username,password:yourpassword}`
```

because the string in back quotes `` which is in the double quotes is not raw string literals, of course it's invalid json. you can compose the json string manually:

```
var jsonprep string = "{\"username\":\"" + username + "\",\"password\":\"" + password + "\"}"
```

Comment: In Go you can avoid all the confusing backslash quoting (\") by using ` (backtick) instead of " (double-quote) for the string.